Need help on random sample of stars, GAIA ADQL code
I need to get a sample of random stars and the GAIA DR3 and Astrophysical parameters data, but I can't seem to figure it out. No matter what I do, they are always ordered one way or another (by either temperature, or coordinates now?!). I know ADQL doesn't support random functions.
What should I do? Thank you very much!

Why don't you use a different method to make the random selection (after getting the ordered data from ADQL)? For example, write a program to select lines randomly. For example, print out 24 pages and throw darts at them. For example ....

This was also the recommended approach for the Rubin Data Preview 0 in a Community thread (should be readable to everyone). Download all the object (GaiaDR3) id's into a CSV file using an asynchronous query (so it doesn't timeout) and then make a random sampling of the object Id's and query for those specifically
